# Zoom a div with all proportions to fit into another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs, the #main div that is wrapped around the #content div. The #content has website-like content that is dynamic, but not responsive.

Now I want #content to be as width as #main. The content inside should not brake but zoom the same way it does with the css property 'zoom'. However it should happen dynamically, not in media querys.

Is it possible with CSS only? If not, what is the best Javascript-way to do that?

Comment: Did you try using the property `transform:scale();`?

Comment: @AliSomay Yes, but it is not dynamic (without media querys)

Comment: Then catch the window resize event and scale accordingly. Maybe you can share a fiddle?

Comment: @Paulie_D I know how stackoverflow works and I have no intention of letting someone else do my work. I simply have no approach, and this is why I asked. I hope there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Then the **additional research** applies....

Comment: As I said I know how stackoverflow works. I wouldn't ask if I didn't do research before...